# Cannot define property '_getObservable': object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winjs

I'm facing an issue and I'm not sure why. I'm setting a [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) as a property of a javascript object:

```
var myFile = MethodThatReturnsAFile();
var obj = { file: myFile };
```

The problem comes when I need to 'clone' that object. Based on a lot of SO answers on the matter I've come to use this method for cloning my objects:

```
    for (var pty in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(pty) && target[pty] !== obj[pty])
            target[pty] = obj[pty];
```

Where `obj` is my current object and `target` is the object I want to create, in my case `var target = {}`.
It works fine 'almost' everytime, expect when `obj` has a `StorageFile` in one of its properties. (I get the message from the subject)

I unserstand `Storagefile` is sealed and can't be extended, but why is who (`WinJS?`) trying to extend it? Should I change my `clone` method or should I not have `StorageFile` as property values?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript object properties may be not enumerable and hidden from 'for' or 'Object.keys'

Look defineProperty method https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: I know how the `defineProperty` works, but I'm not the one calling it... WinJS is calling it, thus my app crashes. What I want to know is what should I do in order for my app not to crash when defineProperty gets called